# Functional Loop with user input C++

Tags: c++, loops

So I got an assignment to make a program that allows the user to select three favourite destinations in order. It repeats until the user decides to stop. Once the user decides to discontinue, the program then displays the total votes received for each destination according to preference by the users. One user will have three preferences and if the program repeats four times, it means four users’ preferences are recorded. Therefore a total of 12 preferences are recorded in this instance.

I have tried to limit input for the loop to work but it seems it will only work with a decision which is not necessary at the beginning of the program, which i want to remove altogether.

Also, I have tried to limit output for each of the decisions but it will only run once and then move on to the next choice. Is there any way to get a persistent entry prompt that will only continue after a valid input.

Lastly, is there any way I could improve the code by using switch/break statements instead of if/else?

Here's my code:

```
cout << "Do you want to go forth with this program?\nType y to confirm. The 
program will exit if anything else is entered: ";
cin >> Decision;    


    while (Decision=="y") 
    {

        cout << "\n\nNow please enter the code for which your destination corresponds to: " << endl;    //first decision
        cin >> Choice1;   

            if (Choice1 == 1) 
            {
                LasVegas1++;        
            }

            else if (Choice1 == 2) 
            {
                Tokyo1++;
            }

            if (cin.fail())
            {     
            cout << "Please enter a valid choice" << endl;
            continue;
            }

        cout << " \nNow please enter the second code: " << endl;    //second decision
        cin >> Choice2;

            if (Choice2 == 1) 
            {
                LasVegas2++;        
            }

            else if (Choice2 == 2) 
            {
                Tokyo2++;
            }

            else 
            {
                cout << "\nError! Please enter a valid code as shown above!\n";
                cout << "\nNow please enter the second code: ";
                cin >> Choice2;
            }




        cout << " \nNow please enter the third code: " << endl;  //third decsion
        cin >> Choice3;

            if (Choice3 == 1) 
            {
                LasVegas3++;        
            }

            else 
            {
                cout << "\nError! Please enter a valid code as shown above!\n";
                cout << "\nNow please enter the third code: ";
                cin >> Choice3;
            }


        cout << " \nDo you wish to select three more destinations? (Y/N): " << endl;
        cin >> Decision;

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to list all the eleven options in order to illustrate the problem.

Comment: And I'm fairly sure that you have learned about vectors or arrays recently. And possibly the "do-while" loop, as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet started with vectors or arrays for that matter. Is there a possible workaround for that matter?

Comment: A switch statement won't make it any more readable but it will make it require less typing, in my opinion you should define some constant for the places `#define LasVegas 1` then you can do `if(choice == LasVegas)` which in my opinion would very much improve the code

Comment: Why do you want to have separate variables for `rome1`, `rome2`, and `rome3`?

Comment: Since Rome can be selected thrice in one loop? I did it for all places

Comment: But why would you want them to be separate? I would think you'd just want to have one `rome` so that it'd show that it has been selected three times

Comment: Basically, my output should show which place was selected how many times and in which choice in a table. For example, if Rome was selected first, it would be printed under choice 1, Paris under choice 2 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be heavily simplified by the use of "**Switch**" and "**Break**".

Like the code that i have written. Have a look :

char input;

int choice;

void Permission() {

```
cout << "Do you want to go forth with this program ?                     (y to confirm)" << flush;
cin >> input;
cout << endl;
```

}

void Decision1() {

if(input == 'y') {

```
    cout << "Now please enter the code for which your destination corresponds to : " << flush;
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
    case 1: 
        cout << "LasVegas " << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Tokyo " << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "London " << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Paris " << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Dubai " << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "Mumbai " << endl;
        break;
    case 7:
        cout << "New York " << endl;
        break;
    case 8:
        cout << "Sydney " << endl;
        break;
    case 9:
        cout << "Auckland " << endl;
        break;
    case 10:
        cout << "Rome " << endl;
        break;
    case 11:
        cout << "Other " << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid option. Enter Again : " << flush;
        cin >> choice;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

}

void Decision2() {

```
cout << "Now please enter the second code: " << flush;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {

case 1:
    cout << "LasVegas " << endl;
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Tokyo " << endl;
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "London " << endl;
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "Paris " << endl;
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "Dubai " << endl;
    break;
case 6:
    cout << "Mumbai " << endl;
    break;
case 7:
    cout << "New York " << endl;
    break;
case 8:
    cout << "Sydney " << endl;
    break;
case 9:
    cout << "Auckland " << endl;
    break;
case 10:
    cout << "Rome " << endl;
    break;
case 11:
    cout << "Other " << endl;
default:
    cout << "Invalid option. Enter Again : " << flush;
    cin >> choice;
}
cout << endl;
```

}

void Decision3() {

```
cout << "Now please enter the third code: " << flush;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    cout << "LasVegas " << endl;
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Tokyo " << endl;
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "London " << endl;
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "Paris " << endl;
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "Dubai " << endl;
    break;
case 6:
    cout << "Mumbai " << endl;
    break;
case 7:
    cout << "New York " << endl;
case 8:
    cout << "Sydney " << endl;
    break;
case 9:
    cout << "Auckland " << endl;
    break;
case 10:
    cout << "Rome " << endl;
    break;
case 11:
    cout << "Other " << endl;
    break;
default:
    cout << "Invalid option. Enter Again : " << flush;
    cin >> choice;
}
cout << endl;
```

}

int main() {

```
Permission();
Decision1();
Decision2();
Decision3();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

I don't know that how to get the loop at the default when the user enters the wrong option. I was able to give the "**cin**" once. Update this problem if you know how to.

Comment: It reduced the repeat input of the user and it didn't required to get the specific variables of the country like **string rome**...... and so on

Comment: And please let me know if you are able to get the loop for the default input of the user...... as i was only able to get the **cin** once

Comment: I Found the Fix for the loop of the default. Its not really the loop but will the ask the user again and again for the right input if the input is not from the list of 1-11.You can add the **goto** statement to get the default back to the starting point of the function. First u will have to create the label. Lable will the point where the goto will jump to . For ex : lable : "code in this part" goto label;.

Comment: Here's the link to the code : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93b683af2dc64534                          Hope it Helps.......

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to put all your city variables into an `array` and then convert your three sets of code into a `for loop`. Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(Choice1 == 0) {
       rome[i]++;
    }
    //etc
```

So that way you wouldn't need to repeat the same code three times. Also you only need one `Choice` variable. (You can just reset it at each iteration of the loop)

Additionally you could implement a `switch` statement to clean up the code a little:

```
switch(Choice1) {  
        case 1:
            LasVegas1++;        
            break;

        case 2:
            Tokyo1++;
            break;

        case 3:
            London1++;
            break;

        case 4:
            Paris1++;
            break;

        case 5:
            Dubai1++;
            break;

        case 6:
            Mumbai1++;
            break;

       case 7:
            NewYork1++;
            break;

        case 8: 
         Sydney1++;
         break;

        case 9:
            Auckland1++;
            break;

        case 10:
            Rome1++;
         break;

        case 11:
            Other1++;
           break;
      }
```

Comment: Alright, your code seems to work but I have two more difficulties. I am supposed to format my output which would look something like this

Rome Choice1[x] Choice2[x] Choice3[x]; Paris Choice1[x] etc. in a table format

with x being how many times it was selected, but your code exits after one cycle of three inputs. It should repeat however many times the user wants. Would it also be possible to put in a persistent error message that will only proceed with a valid input?

Comment: @Datboi What I posted shouldn't be the full code. You should still have your `while` loop that continues while the user inputs `y`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you could improve with a switch statement. Theres also something called a do while loop you should look into.